# Big book Text completion

Tags: word-usage

I need answer and explanation of this question

Even though in today's Soviet Union the ____ the Muslim clergy have been accorded power and privileges, the Muslim laity and the rank-and-file clergy still have little ____ to practice their religion.

(A) practitioners among .. opportunity

(B) dissidents within .. obligation

(C) adversaries of .. inclination

(D) leaders of .. latitude

(E) traditionalists among .. incentive

I found the answer is D. But I don't get the logic. I guess There's a contrast between power and little latitude, laity and leader.

Comment: Sorry, we're not here to just do your homework for you. You need to at least tell us which *you* think is correct & why.

Comment: Which do *you* think it is, and why? Or which do you think it is *not*, and why. This isn't the place to get pat answers for homework!

Comment: This isn't testing English - it requires real-world knowledge of the sociopolitical circumstances of muslims in Russia

Comment: Is it a 'comprehension test' of a previous passage?

Comment: I found the answer is D. But I didn't get the logic.  I guess There's a contrast between power and little latitude, laity and leader.

Comment: "Today's Soviet Union"...  I feel that this textbook might be over thirty years out of date.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  The syntax of the sentence alone offers enough guidance. You don't need to know about muslims in Russia.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, all are fine.  So look at the meaning. The second phrase mentions "rank-and-file clergy". "Rank-and-file" means "ordinary members, not leaders".  The clergy mentioned at the start are contrasted with "rank-and-file" So we need a descriptive phrase that means the opposite to "rank-and-file". Ie "Leaders of".

The second word could be any of the options, but "latitude" works, because it means "freedom", and I guess in the USSR, Muslims didn't have much freedom.

Answer (score 0):

**even though** introduces a  subordinate clause that concedes a fact which the matrix clause will contradict in some manner, setting up a contrast.

Let's look first at the matrix clause with subject highlighted:

> *the Muslim laity and the rank-and-file clergy* still have little ____ to practice their religion

Now for the subordinate clause with its subject highlighted (noting that the subject has a gap):

> Even though in today's Soviet Union the *____ the Muslim clergy* have been accorded power and privileges

If we  scan the options, does anything jump out as being the opposite of the subject in the matrix clause? Yes, **leaders** is the opposite of "laity and rank-and-file clergy".

(A) practitioners among .. opportunity

(B) dissidents within .. obligation

(C) adversaries of .. inclination

(D) **leaders** of .. latitude

(E) traditionalists among .. incentive

All choices but  D) have subjects which are apples-and-oranges with "the Muslim laity and the rank-and-file clergy".

And does **latitude** fit well into the object slot of the original? Yes, it does, as it means "freedom to act". The leaders are granted *powers and privileges* BUT the laity and the lowest ranks of the clergy still have little *freedom* to practice their religion.

Even if you don't see "powers and privileges" as the perfect opposite of *freedom* (those powers could be circumscribed and the privileges could be like giving a cockatoo in a cage some extra juicy fruit), the subject opposition is quite clear.